# Append recursively each record from dictionary to obtain values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, record, defaultdict

Following my question submitted in the last few days, i have a defaultdict which contains in each of the lines a record of the ticket sale for a deviceID, or passenger for a bus sale. The whole devicedict contains all the tickets sold  for a given year, around 1 million.The defaultdict is indexed by the deviceID which is the key. 
I need to know  the average  delay between the purchase date and the actual date of departure for each ticket purchase. My problem is that i can't seem to extract each record from the dictionary.

So devicedict contains for each key devicedict[key] a list of over 60 diferent characteristics: date_departure, date_arrival etc. In each turn of the loop i want to process something like devicedict[deviceID][field of interest] do something with it, and for example extract the median delay between each purchase.

I've tried using append, and using nested arrays, but it doesnt return each individual record by itself.

ValoresDias is the sum of the delays for each ticket(purchase date minus departure) in seconds divided by a day-86400, and ValoresTotalesDias is just an increment variable. The total median delay should be ValoresDias/ValoresTotalesDias for all the records.

```
with open('Salida1.csv',newline='', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    #rows1 = list(csv_reader)
    #print(len(rows1))
    line_count = 0
    count=0
    for row in csv_reader:
        key = row[20]
        devicedict[key].append(row)
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1

        else:
            #print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[20]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            #print(row['id'], row['idapp'])
            #print(len(row))
            #print(list(row))
            mydict5ordenado.append(list(row))
            line_count += 1
    print(len(devicedict.keys())) 




f = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
p = devicedict.keys()
 for i in range(0,len(devicedict)):
        mydict.append(devicedict[list(p)[i]])
        print(mydict[i])
        print("Los campos temporales:")
        #print(mydict[i][4])
        #print(mydict[i][3])
        out1=datetime.datetime.strptime(mydict[i][4], f)
        out2=datetime.datetime.strptime(mydict[i][3], f)    
        out3=out1-out2
        valoresTotalesDias+=1
        valoresDias+=out3.seconds/86400 

       #This is what i am trying to obtain for each record without  hardcoding
       #I want to access each field in the above loop
       count1=len(devicedict['4ff70ad8e2e74f49'])
       for i  in range(0,count1):
       mydict5.append(devicedict['4ff70ad8e2e74f49'][i])
       print(len(mydict5))    
       for i in range (0,len(mydict5)):
         print(mydict5[i][7])
         print("Tipo de Bus:")
         print(mydict5[i][16])
         print(mydict5[i][14])
         if (mydict5[i][16]=='P'):
            preferente+=1
```

Mydict[i] should contain only one line of the record, that is one sale for each passenger not the whole record.

Comment: Please make this a complete example. We don't know what `devicedict`, `p`, `mydict`, `f`, `valoresTotalesDias`, or `valoresDias` are. (Alternatively, remove the lines that aren't necessary for reproducing the issue.)

Comment: we also don't know what the dictionary itself looks like, which is important. Can you edit your question to show us?

Comment: I've edited the question, you can see now the whole code. Salida contains all the records. I've also added information about what i want to do.

Comment: In my rest service, i receive the deviceID and so i can obtain the values for each of the fields. I want to do  the same in the loop, for each of the keys.